# RewriteRule base and specific path

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've basically developed a custom framework for myself that runs all from the index.php using the following .htaccess line

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [QSA,L]
```

I have now developed an REST API that I need to run via the same server/root, I've tried adding the following URL to the .htaccess only to be prompted with a custom 404 I've got intergrated into my custom framework, so basically it's ignoring this line and just trying to use the **RewriteRule** for my custom framework

```
RewriteRule /api/v1/(.*)$ myAPI.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

How can I get it so I my API url won't be passed as a query to my other **RewriteRule**

My .htaccess looks like the following

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=10

AddType "text/html; charset=UTF-8" html 
AddType "text/plain; charset=UTF-8" txt

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # if file not exists
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    # if dir not exists
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # avoid 404s of missing assets in our script
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(jpe?g|png|gif|css|js)$ [NC]

    # rest api url
    RewriteRule ^api/v1/(.*)$ /myAPI.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

    # core framework url rewriting
    RewriteRule .* index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove leading slash from your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^api/v1/(.*)$ /myAPI.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

`.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.

Comment: it's still ignoring the **RewriteRule**, I've added my .htaccess to the question

Comment: Can you try commenting out file exists and directory exists lines and retest?

Comment: I commented out to no avail

Comment: Do you have any .htaccess in `/api/` OR in `/api/v1/`

Comment: `/api/` and `/api/v1/` are not valid directories, they're used for the **RewriteRule** only

Comment: OK got it. Are there any rules in this .htaccess that are working for you?

Comment: everything apart from the `api/v1` **RewriteRule**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40505/discussion-between-curtis-and-anubhava)